# Keep left margin of a div inline with another div when resizing

Tags: css, reactjs, window-resize

the problem that I'm having is that when I resize the browser the left margins of both the  and my card divs aren't aligning. Is there some sort of css property or maybe some JS that will make them stay aligned when resizing?

here's my sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-christian-tosys?file=/src/styles.css:0-

[image: align them together like this]

Comment: You mean you want the bar on top to be the same width as the cards below?

Comment: I want the top bar's left margin staying inline with the left margin when you resize your broswer

Comment: In that case, instead of doing separate margins for the top bar and the row of cards, you could just add `padding: 0 80px;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to the body.  If I'm understanding you correctly, that should solve your problem.  Also, remove the`margin: 0 80px` from the .filter element.

Comment: @isaacsan123 i did that but their still not aligning. I've attached a photo to show you what i mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `.filter` margin `margin: 0 80px;` to your `.row`. and then remove `justify-content: center;`. It will loose the centered. But will be align on the left. To aviod the overflow from the body, you can set `width: calc(100% - 160px);`to your `.row`:

```css
/* ADDED BELOW */
  margin: 0 80px;
  justify-content: unset;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
```

After if you want to keep your card more center, either you use `justify-content: space-between;` on row, either you use `margin: 10px auto;` on your card.

DEMO:

```css
body {
  margin: 0 auto;

  max-width: 1200px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*ADDED BELOW */
  margin: 0 80px;
  justify-content: unset;
  width: calc(100% - 160px);
}

.filter {
  display: flex;

  margin: 0 80px;
}

.filter select {
  display: inline;
  width: 15rem;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.card {
  width: 15rem;
  margin: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
}

.info {
  padding: 15px;
}

.img-container {
  padding-top: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.card img {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.price {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="root">
   <div class="App">
      <div class="filter-container">
         <div class="product-listing-wrap">
            <div class="filter">
               <select class="custom-select" id="priceGroup">
                  <option value="1">Under $50</option>
                  <option value="2">$50 to $100</option>
                  <option value="3">$100 to $250</option>
                  <option value="4">Over $250</option>
               </select>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="
               margin: 0 80px;
               padding: 10px 0;
               width: calc(100% - 160px);
               ">
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="1"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="2"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="3"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="4"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="5"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="6"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="7"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="card">
                  <div class="img-container"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/593171/pexels-photo-593171.jpeg?auto=compress&amp;cs=tinysrgb&amp;dpr=1&amp;w=500" alt="8"></div>
                  <div class="info">
                     <p class="info-title"><span><a>placeholder...</a></span></p>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

try it:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin: 0 80px;
    max-width: 1040px;
    flex-flow: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I downvoted your answer, please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and provide better explication than _"try it:"_. Posting an answer without explication does not help the user from asking it again later.